# How can I use color dialog box in ASP.Net and apply that color to label text using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a label and 2 buttons on aspx page, one to select a color and another to SAVE the color.

1) When I click on the first button, a color dialog box opens. The selected color has to be applied to the label text.

2) When I click on the save button, the color property of label has to get saved, so that next time when I run the code the color selected earlier has to appear.

Comment: If you post the code you have, we can help you better. What did you mean by saying "next time when I run the code"? Is it like next time in the same session? Or can be few days later?

Comment: "next time when I run the code"? it is like few days later? Sorry  i am not getting how to code for this, please help me. Thanku.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, here are the steps to achieve what you want:

1) When the user clicks on the first button and selects a color, you put the color code (e.g. `#ff0000`) the label. To do that you need some [library like this](http://jscolor.com/).

2) When the user clicks on the save button, the form will post back and in your C# code-behind, you need to save the value of the label in a cookie. You need something like [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287547%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
// Set the cookie value.
myCookie.Value = MyColorLabel.Text;
// Set the cookie expiration date.
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
// Add the cookie.
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

3) Finally, next time when loading the page, you read the color from the cookie with [code like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287533%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
myCookie = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];

// Read the cookie information and display it.
if (myCookie != null)
   MyColorLabel.Text = myCookie.Value;
else
   MyColorLabel.Text = "Pick a Color";
```